# Is there a fee payable when applying to a First Tier Tribunal for recovery of a prohibited payment?

Tags: england-and-wales, fees, tribunal

If so, how much is the fee? Tenant Fees Act 2019 provides a special procedure and form TFA1 to recover banned fees, but must one pay a fee to file such an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it's £100.

See the schedule to the [Civil Proceedings, First-tier Tribunal, Upper Tribunal and Employment Tribunals Fees (Amendment) Order 2016](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/807/schedule/made) which substitutes Schedule 1 of the [First-tier Tribunal (Property Chamber) Fees Order 2013](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2013/11) to include:

> *Column 1 Number and description of fee*
>
> 1.1 Where no other fee is specified, on filing an application to commence proceedings in any leasehold case or on filing an appeal or **an application to commence proceedings in a residential property case.**
>
> *Column 2 Amount of fee*
>
> **£100**

Comment: Is it okay to ask what your research process for this question that led to the answeur looked like?

Comment: I had an inkling it was the standard fee of £100, but used a [Life Line](https://millionaire.fandom.com/wiki/Phone-a-Friend) to be sure.